# confirm() breaks decodeAudioBuffer() callback in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

In my HTML5 Web Audio API app, I'm loading a large bunch of audio files in background, more or less like this (nothing really fancy):

```
GET(
    sound.url,
    function(response) {
      ctx.decodeAudioData(
          response,
          function(buffer) {
            buffers[sound.url] = buffer;
            on_buffer_load(sound.url);
          },
          function() {
            fail(
                "failed to decode sound", sound.id,
                "from", sound.url
              );
          }
        );
    },
    function(response, status) {
      fail(
          "failed to load sound", sound.id,
          "from", sound.url,
          "response:", status, response
        );
    },
    "arraybuffer"
  )
```

Meanwhile user is free to do some stuff in the UI — as long as what he is doing does not require a loaded sound.

It seems, that if user triggers a `confirm()` call while sounds are loading, `decodeAudioData()` skips a callback or two — neither success nor failure callbacks are called for some of the sounds.

Is this something to be expected? Or should I dig deep and try produce a minimal example and submit a bug? What am I missing?

Comment: Reported as bug: [http://crbug.com/395819](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395819 "audioContext.decodeAudioData callbacks are not invoked when a modal dialog is open").